# Improve node spacing using tikz graphs (no LuaTex)

Tags: tikz-graphs

Here is an example graph I have created. I am trying to increase node separation. Also any recommendations on a more compact way to write this would be appreciated. Note: baseline is because this is from a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
    \tikz[baseline] \graph[grid placement, wrap after=2] {
        000;
        111;
        011;
        001;
        110;
        010;
        101;
        100;
        000 -- {001, 010, 100};
        111 -- {110, 101, 011};
        110 -- {100, 010};
    };
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `grow right=2.5cm` in the `\graph`'s options.